# Choosing input for AWS Lambda RequestHandler

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to understand if I can provide a custom event as input to `RequestHandler`.

The documentation provided [by AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-handler.html#java-handler-types) says :

> If you define your own input type, it should be a deserializable, mutable plain old Java object (POJO), with a default constructor and properties for each field in the event.

Consider `KafkaEvent` from [aws-lambda-java-events](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-java-libs/tree/master/aws-lambda-java-events).
So, would this class work ?

```
public class LambdaInput extends KafkaEvent implements Cloneable, Serializable {
     // nothing inside
}
```

It's not strictly a POJO but has no members or itself.

What if `LambdaInput` had members apart from whats in `KafkaEvent` ? Would it still be a valid input for `RequestHandler` ?